# Word interop, disabling save prompt

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

How do you disable the save prompt.

```
class WordDocument
{
    Word.Document document; 

    public WordDocument(string filepath,Word.Application application)
    {
        document = application.Documents.Open(filepath);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        document.Save();
        //need to remove prompt
    }
}
```

Comment: This mostly wasn't about saving originally. I felt this was too vague, so i took most of it out. Should be able to accept an answer for it now, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the propt to save windows set application.DisplaAlerts = false before saving the doc